# Changing fonts and sizes in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, times, arial

Somebody would like to use Times New Roman and  Arial fonts in their document including a 13pt size version. Can this be done? Here's a nonworking MWE:

```
  % wordprob.tex SE 541134

\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{mathptmx} % Times font
% for chapters
\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\Large\bfseries} % 17pt bold (but add Arial)
% for sections, etc
%\renewcommand{\setsecheadstyle}{\large\itshape\bfseries} % 14pt bold italic (but add Arial)
\renewcommand{\setsecheadstyle}{\large\itshape} % 14pt bold italic (but add Arial)
\setbeforesecskip{-12pt plus 1ex minus .2ex}
\setaftersecskip{12pt plus .2ex}
\renewcommand{\setsubsecheadstyle}{\normalsize\bfseries} % 13pt not usually supported (but add Arial)
\setbeforesubsecskip{-12pt plus 1ex minus .2ex}
\setaftersubsecskip{3pt plus .2ex}
% page numbering
\makepagestyle{wordprob}
  \makeevenfoot{wordprob}{}{}{\thepage}
  \makeoddfoot{wordprob}{}{}{\thepage}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{wordprob}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{wordprob}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[2-3]
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\lipsum[3-5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no good arial support unless you use one of the unicode engines and fontspec or use helvetica instead. 13pt can always be used with \fontsize{13pt}{15pt}\selectfont.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you.